# Lazy loading in map view?

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

I have to show large set of location records in tableview and mapview depends on user switching between views. How lazy loading can be implemented?. I don't want query central server for location for even small change in location.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data are you lazily loading?  If you're talking about annotations for your locations then MKMapView already handles lazy loading for you based on the region of the map.  You just give it an array of your annotations and it will handle the lazy loading of the actual annotation views.  If you mean something else, then please specify.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have 16000 records on server and i need to display around 200 records aprrox. based on user location. then i need to show remaining while user does mapview panning. if i populate 200 records while loading app then it takes long time to show map.how to overcome this?